# Search in Matrix Fields

Tags: matrix

I am using simple search tag in EE, and for some reason, the search results don't show pages in which the search term is in Matrix fields. I do have those fields set to searchable in Matrix so I am very confused.

Here is my EE template form structure:

{exp:search:simple_form channel="disability_topics2" search_in="everywhere" result_page="/search" status="not closed" where="all" show_expired="yes" show_future_entries="yes"}
Search Site:


{/exp:search:simple_form}

What can I do?

In the entry publish page I have a Wygwam field for the "main page content" and then a Matrix field with two text areas (which are set to searchable). However, when I do a search, it will pull up entries with search terms in the "main page content" field, but not the Matrix field.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks!

Michael

Comment: Is the matrix field itself set to searchable? (Not the columns)

Comment: I'm such a bonehead. It was not. Now it is and it works. Thanks! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure the Matrix field itself is set to searchable as well as the appropriate Matrix columns (see screenshot).

If your column wasn’t set to Searchable already, you’ll need to re-save your entries for the change to take effect.

[image: Matrix Settings]

Comment: Jason can you expand your answer with more detail/screenshots about how to check each of these settings?