# Search Parameter within Matrix Field

Tags: matrix, search, parameters

Is there an easy way to search within a Matrix field for a particular value and if it matches to display the associated entry? Similar to how the "search:" parameter allows you to constrain Channel Entries output based on content within your fields. I want to do something like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="shows"
    search:show_uid="={segment_2}"
    limit="1"
    show_expired="yes"
    dynamic="off"
}
```

"show_uid" is the name of my Matrix field and the value I'm trying to match is in column 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mark a Matrix column as Searchable, then its content will be stored as keywords on the parent entry, and you will be able to search for it via {exp:channel:entries}’ `search:field_name=` param.

Couple caveats, though:

- Remember that we’re just talking about *keywords* here. You can’t search for specific cell values, since those values are just getting dumped along with all other cells’ values for all of your searchable columns. So don’t prefix your `search:field_name=` param value with `=`, e.g. `search:field_name="=somevalue"`.
- If you set a column to Searchable after you’ve already saved some entries, you will need to re-save those entries for the setting to take effect.

Comment: What is being set in the database when the entry is re-saved?

Comment: The relevant change, as far as this Searchable setting is concerned, is that the columns’ search keywords will be included in the data Matrix stores in the exp_channel_entries table. That’s the table that the `search:field_name=` parameters will query against.

Answer (score 0):

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#search-field-name

You can search in matrix fields, no problem! Just make sure that the matrix column is set to **searchable**. Check this answer for some pictures:

[Search in Matrix Fields](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/4761/search-in-matrix-fields)

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="shows"
    search:show_uid="={segment_2}"
    limit="1"
    show_expired="yes"
    dynamic="off"
}

    If you're seeing this, it's because we have a search result within the matrix field you wanted to search in!

{/exp:channel:entries}
```